# graylog-ctl reconfigure error in script default.rb

Tags: chef-infra, virtual-machine, graylog

1/
I discovered the wonderful graylog2 which I manage to run on a VM running Ubuntu 14.04

. I would like to update it to graylog 1.1.3 but I can't figure out how. 
My source was this url : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-graylog2-and-centralize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04

2/
I tried to take over that problem by installing the offical VM graylog_ova, opened in Vmware Workstation. There, I started to update the conf files in /opt/graylog/conf... I have now an error when I execute graylog-ctl reconfigure.

Do you have some good ideas my dear fellows ?

```
  ================================================================================
  Recipe Compile Error in /opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/graylog/recipes/default.rb
  ================================================================================

  Chef::Exceptions::JSON::ParseError
  ----------------------------------
  parse error: after key and value, inside map, I expect ',' or '}'
            t_address": "192.168.0.4"   "last_address": "192.168.0.4",
                       (right here) ------^

  Cookbook Trace:
  ---------------
    /opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/graylog/libraries/graylog.rb:136:in `generate_settings'
    /opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/graylog/libraries/graylog.rb:228:in `generate_config'
    /opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/graylog/recipes/default.rb:13:in `from_file'

  Relevant File Content:
  ----------------------
  /opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/graylog/libraries/graylog.rb:

  129:      def enabled?(service)
  130:        Graylog[service.gsub('-', '_')]['enabled']
  131:      end
  132:
  133:      def generate_settings
  134:        existing_settings ||= Hash.new
  135:        if File.exists?("/etc/graylog/graylog-settings.json")
  136>>         existing_settings = Chef::JSONCompat.from_json(File.read("/etc/graylog/graylog-settings.json"))
  137:        end
  138:        existing_settings.each do |k, v|
  139:          Graylog[k] = v
  140:        end
  141:
  142:        Graylog['timezone']        = Graylog[:node]['graylog']['timezone'] if Graylog['timezone'].empty?
  143:        Graylog['smtp_server']     = Graylog[:node]['graylog']['smtp_server'] if Graylog['smtp_server'].nil?
  144:        Graylog['smtp_port']       = Graylog[:node]['graylog']['smtp_port'] if Graylog['smtp_port'].nil?
  145:        Graylog['smtp_user']       = Graylog[:node]['graylog']['smtp_user'] if Graylog['smtp_user'].nil?


  Running handlers:
[2015-06-29T15:27:39+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
  Running handlers complete
[2015-06-29T15:27:39+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-06-29T15:27:39+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
  Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.958758246 seconds
[2015-06-29T15:27:39+02:00] ERROR: parse error: after key and value, inside map, I expect ',' or '}'
          t_address": "192.168.0.4"   "last_address": "192.168.0.4",
                     (right here) ------^

[2015-06-29T15:27:39+02:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

et

```
Generated at 2015-06-29 15:25:34 +0200
Chef::Exceptions::JSON::ParseError: parse error: after key and value, inside map, I expect ',' or '}'
          t_address": "192.168.0.4"   "last_address": "192.168.0.4",
                     (right here) ------^

/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/json_compat.rb:52:in `rescue in parse'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/json_compat.rb:49:in `parse'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/json_compat.rb:58:in `from_json'
/opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/graylog/libraries/graylog.rb:136:in `generate_settings'
/opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/graylog/libraries/graylog.rb:228:in `generate_config'
/opt/graylog/embedded/cookbooks/graylog/recipes/default.rb:13:in `from_file'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `from_file'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:228:in `load_recipe'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/run_context.rb:173:in `load_recipe'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:140:in `block in compile_recipes'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `each'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `compile_recipes'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:75:in `compile'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/run_context.rb:96:in `load'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:73:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/client.rb:249:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/client.rb:446:in `run'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application.rb:271:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application.rb:259:in `fork'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application.rb:259:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application.rb:225:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:38:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application.rb:213:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:275:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:264:in `loop'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:264:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:242:in `run_application'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
/opt/graylog/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.2.1/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/graylog/embedded/bin/chef-solo:23:in `load'
/opt/graylog/embedded/bin/chef-solo:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: please use correct formatting for code.

Comment: Done ! Sorry about that... Would you have an idea ?

Comment: Well I solved it myself. For the record, I accidentally erased a comma in graylog-settings.json in /etc/graylog/